# SOAP client not handling XML entities properly; encountering "There is an error in XML document"

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, xmlserializer, soap-client

Some consumers of our WCF web service are encountering an exception when trying to parse our responses:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (5, -349).
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>    at [Consumer's Code]
> ```

The inner exception looks like this:

> ```
> '', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character. Line 5, position -349.
>
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseNumericCharRefInline(Int32 startPos, Boolean expand, BufferBuilder internalSubsetBuilder, Int32& charCount, EntityType& entityType)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCharRefInline(Int32 startPos, Int32& charCount, EntityType& entityType)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>    at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
>    at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read43_TextWidgetConfig(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read45_TextWidgetInfo(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read49_WidgetInfo(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read50_InstantPageData(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read128_GetInstantPageDataResponse()
>    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer141.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> ```

The customer's data being returned somehow had vertical tab characters in it.  Looking at our XML, we could see that these characters were being properly rendered as `&#xB;` entities.  Doing a quick Google search, we found that there is a bug with `XmlSerializer` where it can't handle certain entities, which has to be fixed by changing an option in the the auto-generated proxies' XML Readers.

The consumer acknowledges that they need to fix their client-side code, but they are unable to quickly respond to this issue with a patch.  They would like us to apply a patch in our own code to filter out these forbidden characters.

1. Is the list of problem characters for `XmlSerializer` documented anywhere?
2. Is there a clean way for us to change our WCF service so that we can automatically strip out characters without resorting to doing string replaces in all of our web methods?

**Update:**

I found the answer to #1.  According to [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char), only certain character codes are allowed:

> Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

So it seems like the `DataContractSerializer` on our server is what's in error here.  I'm looking into how to customize that serializer now.

**Update 2:**

It looks like the `DataContractSerializer` issue is known and [logged in Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/465688/data-contract-serializer-violates-xml-specification-1-0-and-1-1).

Comment: So, your customer is giving you malformed XML and expects you to implement a hack to take care of their problem? That's just going to give them a reason NOT to fix their end.

Comment: No, we're serving up somewhat-malformed XML (with entities out of the allowed character ranges) generated by the `DataContractSerializer` to a consumer of our web service.  Even WebService Studio chokes on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my workaround code.  I'm not super happy about it; it doesn't cover all cases (though it takes care of my needs), and it feels like there should be an easier solution.  I'll post it here with the hopes that someone else can make it better or that someone has an easier answer.

To work around the issue, I created a new operation behavior attribute to change the serializer to a custom serializer that would strip out characters that would be rendered as invalid XML entities:

```
public class StripInvalidXmlCharactersBehaviorAttribute 
    : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(
        OperationDescription operationDescription, 
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(
        OperationDescription operationDescription, 
        ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        IOperationBehavior behavior =
            new StripInvalidXmlCharactersBehavior(operationDescription);
        behavior.ApplyClientBehavior(operationDescription, clientOperation);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
        OperationDescription operationDescription, 
        DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        IOperationBehavior behavior =
            new StripInvalidXmlCharactersBehavior(operationDescription);
        behavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(
            operationDescription, dispatchOperation);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }
}
```

The behavior itself looks like this:

```
internal class StripInvalidXmlCharactersBehavior 
    : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public StripInvalidXmlCharactersBehavior(OperationDescription opDesc)
        : base(opDesc)
    {
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(
        Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new InvalidXmlStrippingSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(
        Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, 
        IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new InvalidXmlStrippingSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }
}
```

And this is the serializer:

```
internal class InvalidXmlStrippingSerializer : XmlObjectSerializer
{
    private DataContractSerializer _innerSerializer;

    public InvalidXmlStrippingSerializer(
        Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        _innerSerializer = 
            new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public InvalidXmlStrippingSerializer(
        Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, 
        IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        _innerSerializer =
            new DataContractSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public override bool IsStartObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
    {
        return _innerSerializer.IsStartObject(reader);
    }

    public override object ReadObject(
        XmlDictionaryReader reader, bool verifyObjectName)
    {
        return _innerSerializer.ReadObject(reader, verifyObjectName);
    }

    public override void WriteEndObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        _innerSerializer.WriteEndObject(writer);
    }

    public override void WriteObjectContent(
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
    {
        graph = fixBadStringsRecursive(graph);
        _innerSerializer.WriteObjectContent(writer, graph);
    }

    private object fixBadStringsRecursive(object graph)
    {
        var objType = graph.GetType();
        if (objType == typeof(string))
        {
            graph = removeInvalidCharacters(graph as string);
        }
        else if (graph is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in graph as IEnumerable)
            {
                fixBadStringsRecursive(item);
            }
        }
        else if (objType.IsClass)
        {
            // Look through the properties of the object 
            foreach (var prop in graph.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var propParams = prop.GetIndexParameters();
                if ((propParams == null || propParams.Length == 0)
                    && prop.GetGetMethod() != null)
                {
                    var propVal = prop.GetValue(graph, null);
                    if (propVal != null)
                    {
                        propVal = fixBadStringsRecursive(propVal);
                        if (prop.GetSetMethod() != null)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(graph, propVal, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return graph;
    }

    private static string removeInvalidCharacters(string source)
    {
        // This is per the W3C XML spec:
        // http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char
        return new string(
            (
                from ch in source
                where
                    ch == '\u0009' || ch == '\u000a' || ch == '\u000d'
                    || (ch >= '\u0020' && ch <= '\ud7ff')
                    || (ch >= '\ue000' && ch <= '\ufffd')
                select ch
            ).ToArray()
        );
    }

    public override void WriteStartObject(
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
    {
        _innerSerializer.WriteStartObject(writer, graph);
    }
}
```

To apply the behavior to my operation, I can now just add the attribute I created.